# Delphi: Filtering result of left outer join query

Tags: sql, delphi

I have a query with `left outer join` clause gathering results from two tables (I use `TZQuery` component but it probably does not matter here).

I would like to use filter to display only results where column called ABC contains XXX.

My first approach is:

```
MyQuery.Filter := 'ABC = XXX';
MyQuery.Filtered := True;
```

It does not work though.

I believe the reason is that my query gathers results from two tables.

What is a proper solution here?

Thank you!

Comment: Explain "does not work". Provide an extract of rows from your query. What does the filter include/exclude that it should not?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the filter is applied by passing back to the engine, so you have to write your filter as you would the conditionals of a WHERE clause in your SQL.

```
MyQuery.Filter := 'ABC = 1';
MyQuery.Filter := 'ABC <> 1';
MyQuery.Filter := 'ABC = ' + QuotedStr('XXX');
MyQuery.Filter := 'ABC LIKE ' + QuotedStr('%XXX%');
```

your filter will not apply if the conditions are unintelligible to the engine.

Also try and remember to be explicit, if you are using a join and there is potential ambiguity between the field names include the TABLENAME in your filter.

```
MyQuery.Filter := 'TABLENAME.ABC = 1';
```